# How to close colorpicker after onSubmit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, color-picker, eyecon-plugin

[Library Link](https://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)

I am using above library but could not be able to find anywhere that how can I close it by selecting any color without actually clicking anywhere in the screen (They must be using blur).

```
$('#colorSelector'+dynamicID).ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onSubmit: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector'+dynamicID).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

I have tried using this 
`$(selector).colorpicker('close')`
But it did not work but breaks everything.

Comment: wild guess, but try $(selector).colorpicker.hide()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the colorpicker on submit button

```
$('#colorSelector'+dynamicID).ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onSubmit: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector'+dynamicID).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('#colorSelector').hide(); // closes the color picker on submit after selection of color
}
});
```